# appium 7.4.1 is not supporting for qaf version 3.1.0 and selenium 4.2.2

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, qaf, appium-java

We are trying to update qaf and selenium and appium from old versions, we tried to change selenium from 3.141.59 to 4.2.2 , and qmetry 3.0.1 to 3.1.0 and appium 7.4.1 is not supporting for this version .

With this updated version of qaf and selenium web application and api is working.

Kindly provide solution for this .

Tried to upgrade appium to upper version, selenium and qaf version downgraded still not working.

We want to upgrade our versions.
Currently We are using this versions:
QAF:3.0.1
Selenium : 3.141.59
appium:7.4.1

Comment: Appium v7.x does not support Selenium > v3.141.59. You need to upgrade to Appium v8.0+ in order to use Selenium v4.0+. There is migration documentation available, but I have not tried this: https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/v7-to-v8-migration-guide.md

Answer (score 0):

It's because compatibility of appium 7.4.1 with selenium 4. You should either downgrade selenium to 3.141.59 or try with appium 8.0.x or 8.1.x and latest version of QAF (3.1.0 or later) with selenium 4.